# VB.NET Repeater Simple Data Binding Without Datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datarepeater

Im a ASP.NET beginner. I previously asked how to do some databinding to a repeater without a datasourse. Here. [VB.NET Repeater Simple Data Binding Without Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926619/vb-net-repeater-simple-data-binding-without-datasource)

here is the solution someone got for me

```
Dim repeatTimes((TotalAdInsured)) As Integer

    myRepeater.DataSource = repeatTimes
    myRepeater.DataBind()
```

However, I now need to know how to get an index for each item in the repeater. ie

```
<% #index %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAwesome">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItem %> <%# Container.ItemIndex %><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: ok, now have this problem, when I try to do that 'AdTitle<%# Container.DataItem %>' is not a valid identifier.

<asp:DropDownList ID="AdTitle<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server">

Comment: Mark: <%# ... %> is not a preprocessing directive. See here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-compi/370263#370263). In any case, whatever you're attempting to do with the ID property is almost certainly wrong. Post another question which explains exactly what you're trying do.